# Static function PcBaseArModel::getCreatorRelationName() should not be abstract

Tags: yii

как исправить данную ошибку?
Если убрать слово abstract, то выдается Fatal error о том, что ему не хватает абстрактных функций.

```
Fatal error: Non-abstract method PcBaseArModel::getCreatorRelationName() must contain body in
```

Comment: Кто то забыл прочитать про абстрактные классы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте ее абстрактной. И уберите статику.
Оба этих понятия плохо сочетаются, потому что статика - это принадлежность классу, а абстракт - это намек на дальнейшее наследование.

Вторая ошибка возникает, когда вы после объявления неабстрактной функции не стали описывать ее тело. Типа того:

```
function my_non_abstract();
```

вместо

```
function my_non_abstract(){

}
```